# display the data as it is displayed in the screen

Tags: iphone

[image]

Hi, I want to implement a screen like in the image above. The data is coming from the server in the form of JSON string and I have parsed the data.

The code is as follows:

```
         UILabel *lblTitle  = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Seroquel"
                                           contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 20) 
                                                  color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                   font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblTitle];
        [lblTitle release];

        UILabel *lblGeneric       = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Generic Name:"
                                             contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblTitle.frame.size.height+5, 130, 20) 
                                                    color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                     font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblGeneric];
        [lblGeneric release];

        UILabel *lblGenericName   = [self createDynamicLabel:DrugInfo.GenName
                                                contentFrame:CGRectMake(lblGeneric.frame.size.width+5, 24, 150, 20) 
                                                       color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                        font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblGenericName];
        [lblGenericName release];

        UILabel *lblManufacturer  = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Manufacturer:"
                                                contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 44, 115, 20) 
                                                       color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                        font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblManufacturer];
        [lblManufacturer release];

        UILabel *lblManufacturerName = [self createDynamicLabel:DrugInfo.Mtr
                                                   contentFrame:CGRectMake(115, 43, 150, 20) 
                                                          color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                           font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblManufacturerName];
        [lblManufacturerName release];

        //[self createDynamicView:CGRectMake(10, 70, 153, 128)];


        UILabel *lblCommon          = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Common uses:"
                                           contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 209, 110, 20) 
                                                  color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                   font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        lblCommon.backgroundColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [lblCommon sizeToFit];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblCommon];
        [lblCommon release];

        NSString *genericInfo       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"                        %@",DrugInfo.ComUse];
        UILabel *lblCommonUse       = [self createDynamicLabel:genericInfo
                                             contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 208, 310, 80) 
                                                    color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                     font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];


        //[lblCommonUse sizeToFit];
        lblCommonUse.lineBreakMode  = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lblCommonUse.numberOfLines  = 0;
        [scrollview addSubview:lblCommonUse];
        [lblCommonUse release];



        UILabel *lblBefore          = [self createDynamicLabel:@" Before Using:"
                                           contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 294, 102, 20) 
                                                  color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                   font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        [lblBefore sizeToFit];
        lblBefore.backgroundColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrollview addSubview:lblBefore];
        [lblBefore release];

        genericInfo                 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"                        %@",DrugInfo.BeforeUse];
        UILabel *lblBeforeUse       = [self createDynamicLabel:genericInfo
                                             contentFrame:CGRectMake(10, 290, 308, 120) 
                                                    color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                     font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        lblBeforeUse.lineBreakMode  = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lblBeforeUse.numberOfLines  = 0;
        [scrollview addSubview:lblBeforeUse];
        [lblBeforeUse release];


    }  
}
}   


-(UILabel *)createDynamicLabel:(NSString *)setTitle 
              contentFrame:(CGRect)labelFrame 
                     color:(UIColor *)labelColor 
                      font:(UIFont *)labelFont {

UILabel  *dynamicLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
dynamicLabel.frame     = labelFrame;
dynamicLabel.text      = setTitle;
dynamicLabel.textColor = labelColor;
dynamicLabel.font      = labelFont;
dynamicLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return dynamicLabel;
}
```

But if the data is more than can be displayed on the screen, it is clipping it and I want to display all the data. Can any one please help me do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Off, from what I can see you are adding your UI controls to a UIScrollView, if that is the case you need to make sure you are setting the contentSize property of the UIScrollView. The UIScrollView does not know how big the content is hold, so you need to figure this out and tell the UIScrollView.

This can be achieved quite easily if you set the frames for your controls using positioning variables (i.e CGFloat top; CGFloat left;) and update them as you add controls, instead of hardcoding the position values into your code. Something like this

```
CGFloat top = 5;
CGFloat left = 10;   
UILabel *lblTitle  = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Seroquel"
                                       contentFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, 150, 20) 
                                              color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                               font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
[scrollview addSubview:lblTitle];
[lblTitle release];

top += lblTitle.frame.size.height;

UILabel *lblGeneric       = [self createDynamicLabel:@"Generic Name:"
                                         contentFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, 130, 20) 
                                                color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                 font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
[scrollview addSubview:lblGeneric];
[lblGeneric release];

left += lblGeneric.frame.size.width;

UILabel *lblGenericName   = [self createDynamicLabel:DrugInfo.GenName
                                            contentFrame:CGRectMake(left, top, 150, 20) 
                                                   color:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                                    font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
[scrollview addSubview:lblGenericName];
[lblGenericName release];
```

Then at the end, you can use `top` to make a `CGSize` to set the contentSize.

I also would suggest you look at using UITableView or using NSAttributedString as they might help you achieve what you want in other ways.